# A question regarding intersections and products of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Does the following hold for $E, L, K$ fields?

> $$E(L \cap K) = EL \cap EK$$

$$$$
Certainly $E(L \cap K) \subseteq EL \cap EK$ since both $EL$ and $EK$ contain $E$ and $L \cap K$, but I can't see how to handle the reverse inclusion (possibly because it doesn't hold?).  I suppose it boils down to whether or not given
$$\sum_{\text{finite}} e\alpha = \sum_{\text{finite}} f\beta$$
with $e, f \in E$, $\alpha \in L$, and $\beta \in K$, does there exist an expression for this element of the form $\sum g\gamma$ with $g \in E$ and $\gamma \in L \cap K$, though I'm not sure this is the best way to formulate the question.

Comment: Claimed to be false in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674591/relationship-between-intersection-and-compositum-of-fields

Comment: @darijgrinberg I suppose I should have searched for compositums rather than products.

Answer (score 3):

We can find a counterexample in any finite, non-cyclic Galois extension, because the subgroup lattice of a finite group is distributive only for cyclic groups (this is a [result of Ore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_subgroups#Characterizing_groups_by_their_subgroup_lattices)).

Concretely: Set $E = \mathbb{Q}[\omega]$, $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$, $K=\mathbb{Q}[\omega\sqrt[3]{2}]$.  Then $E(L\cap K)=\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$, but $EL\cap EK=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},\omega]$.

Comment: Do you by chance know what happens in the infinite extension case?

Comment: @JacobBond What is it that you want to know?

Comment: Is it also false in the infinite extension case?

Comment: @JacobBond We can adjoin transcendental elements $x,y,z$ to $E,L,K$ to get an infinite-dimensional counterexample.  I don't know if there is a canonical counterexample.